# Select comment()'s before root node

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

This is a distraction turned obsession. I was messing around in eXist and decided to get the `comment()` from the document. Only problem is most of our comments come before the root node. Let's take an example

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- DOCUMENT REVIEWED -->
<doc id="test">
  <figure>
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p>blah blah blah</p>
</doc>
```

## XQUERY

```
xquery version "3.1";
let $col := '/db/project/data'

let $result := <docs> { 
    for $doc in collection($col)/doc
       let $id := string($doc/@id)
       let $figures := count($doc//figures)
       let $comments := ????? 
       return <doc id="{$id}" figurecount="{$figures}">{$comments}</doc>

} </docs>
return $result
```

Now i've tried several things. `ancestor::comment()`, `preceding-sibling`, even `collection($col)//comment()`. I'm able to find a comment before the `<doc>`  in oXygen, simply `//comment()` does the trick.

I don't really need this for anything in specific, but its bugging me that I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Which version of eXist? The 3.1 version declaration suggests it's a relatively recent build from the develop branch of source.

Comment: Also, how are you running this query in eXist? Using eXide?

Comment: I can confirm unexpected results in the current develop branch of eXist. I've filed an issue on eXist's tracker: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/623.

Comment: Hi @joewiz, generally I am using restxq, but in this instance, yes eXide. Additionally, this is from the development branch. I last updated it last week I believe.

Comment: I'll try to keep this thread updated with any actions taken to resolve that issue, but you can also subscribe to that issue if you have a github account, so you're notified immediately if the issue is updated. Thanks for the report.

Comment: @joewiz Thanks. Github is the better place for me. Additionally, I also generally follow the mailing list pretty closely even though I don't participate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is not a descendant of the `<doc>` document; it's a child of the document node, which is a preceding sibling to `<doc>`, so `preceding-sibling::comment()` should have worked.

For example, this is how your document would be constructed from scratch:

```
document {(
  <!-- DOCUMENT REVIEWED -->,
  <doc id="test">
    <figure>
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </doc>
)}
```

So you could select it by starting at the document node:

```
doc('my-doc.xml')/comment()
```

Or you can select its preceding sibling if the context is `<doc>`:

```
doc('my-doc.xml')/doc/preceding-sibling::comment()
```

In eXist, I think `collection()` should return a document node, so you could iterate over that directly, instead of selecting the root element:

```
for $doc-node in collection($col)
let $comment := $doc-node/comment()
let $id := $doc-node/doc/@id
let $figures := count($doc//figures)
return ...
```

Comment: see I thought so too, but it isn't working. Which is why I'm asking. Thanks for attempting +1. I'm wondering if this is an eXist problem now. Maybe I should hit up their mailing list.

Comment: I ran your code in BaseX, using `let $comments := $doc/preceding-sibling::comment()` and it worked fine.  So, it may indeed by specific to eXist.

Comment: @matchew This could be a bug in eXist. It seems unlikely, given that this is (I think) well defined in the spec. But I also ran it in MarkLogic and didn't have the same problem. Posting to their list is a good idea...surely someone has run across this before.

Comment: This now appears to be an eXist issue (https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/623). I'm glad I asked the question here first though, it seems like this could be a good question and I hadn't seen it elsewhere. Thanks!